# Combine category AND custom taxonomy in permalink structure

Tags: permalinks

It seems like this question has been asked not infrequently, but I still can't make heads of it. I followed the [Rewrite API Guide](https://helpstring.wordpress.com/2012/05/24/the-rewrite-api-post-types-taxonomies/) to look at how to merge, but I want something like this:

Category = categories, built in.
Food = custom taxonomy.

When I enter http://mysite.com/food/category to find all posts in that category and that foot type, similar to

http://mysite.com/index.php?category=category&food=food

I'll also have pages, which aren't attached to a "food" or category, and the permalink fails if i simply put %foood%/%category%/ into the permalink settings.

Does anyone have any recommendations?

Comment: how will WordPress distinguish between `food/category` and `parent-page/child-page`? rewrite rules need uniqueness or they'll conflict with each other.

Comment: OK, I'd love help attacking this point then.

Comment: Did you solve your problem @dama_do_bling ? If yes, there are some friends waiting for answer :)

Comment: @Eray see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing was setting up an endpoint for food, like so:

```
global $wp_rewrite;
$wp_rewrite->add_endpoint( 'food', EP_PERMALINK | EP_PAGES );
$wp_rewrite->flush_rules();

function printview_query_vars($vars)
{ array_push($vars, 'food');
  return $vars;
}
add_filter('query_vars','printview_query_vars');
```

Then I'd get a url like `http://mysite/pagename/food/fruits/shelves/` and the wp_query would contain something like `food=>fruits/shelves`, which then i can parse myself into a custom query.